# Доступ к SharedPreferences из самописного класса

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shared-preferences

У меня есть класс, который обрабатывает и сохраняет информацию. Всё сделано на основе `SharedPreferences`. От какого класса надо наследоваться, чтобы работал метод `getSharedPreferences`? Сам попробовал наследоваться от `ContextWrapper`, код представлен ниже. Но получаю

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference

```
class InformationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var context:Context = applicationContext
...
light.text = InfSettings(context).getLight().toString()
...
}

class InfSettings(base: Context?) : ContextWrapper(base) {
    private var gameProfile: SharedPreferences? = getSharedPreferences("settings_info", MODE_PRIVATE)
    private var editorProfile: SharedPreferences.Editor? = null
    private val LIGHT = "person_count_light"
    private var lightGame: Int = 0
    fun setLightGame(lightGame: Int) {
        this.lightGame = lightGame
        editorProfile = gameProfile!!.edit()
        editorProfile!!.putInt(LIGHT, this.lightGame)
        editorProfile!!.apply()
    }
    ...
    fun getLight(): Int {
        return gameProfile!!.getInt(LIGHT, 0)
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучшее, на мой взгляд, решение не наследоваться от `ContextWrapper`, а создать свойство типа `Context` и инициализировать его в конструкторе.

Пример класса:

```
class MyExample(context: Context) {
    val context: Context;

    init {
        this.context = context;
        var str: String = this.context.getSharedPreferences("test", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("test", "123");
    }
}
```

Пример его инициализации:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var example = MyExample(this);
    }
}
```